# problema al pixelar imagen en php

Tags: php, imagen

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es pixelar una imagen de una url, acomplarle otra imagen por encima y por ultimo guardar dicha imagen.

He obtenido este código de internet para pixelar imágenes pero creo que no funciona correctamente. No me muestra la imagen pixelada ni tampoco la guarda. Simplemente se queda la pantalla en negro.

```
<?php 

$pixel = 15;

    $getImagen = 'https://ep00.epimg.net/elpais/imagenes/2017/06/05/album/1496652756_562670_1496654035_album_normal.jpg';


    $imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg($getImagen); 
    if(!$imagen) exit('ERROR');
    list($ancho,$alto)=getimagesize($getImagen);
    $superficieTotal = $ancho*$alto;    
    //
    $superficieRecorrida = 0;
    $auxX=0;
    $auxY=0;
    while($superficieRecorrida <= $superficieTotal){
        $posX=0;$posY=0;$data = array();
        while($posX <= $pixel and (($auxX + $posX) < $ancho)){
            $posY=0;
            while($posY <= $pixel and (($auxY + $posY) < $alto)){
                $rgb = imagecolorat($imagen, ($auxX + $posX), ($auxY + $posY));
                $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
                $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
                $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
                $data[] = array($r,$g,$b);
                $posY++;
            }
            $posX++;
        }

        // Busco promedio
        $r = 0; $g = 0; $b = 0;
        foreach($data as $d){
            $r+= $d[0];
            $g+= $d[1];
            $b+= $d[2];
        }
        $totalArray = count($data);
        if($totalArray == 0) $totalArray = 1;
        $r = $r/$totalArray;
        $g = $g/$totalArray;
        $b = $b/$totalArray;
        $colorPromedio = imagecolorallocate($imagen, $r, $g, $b);
        imagefilledrectangle($imagen, $auxX, $auxY, ($auxX + $pixel), ($auxY + $pixel), $colorPromedio);
        //
        $auxX+= $pixel;
        if($auxX >= $ancho){
            $auxX = 0;
            $auxY+= ($pixel+1);
        }       
        $superficieRecorrida+= $pixel*$pixel;

    }
    //
    Header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($imagen);
    imagedestroy($imagen);
```

Gracias por vuestras futuras respuestas. un saludo.

Comment: Este SO es en español, por favor traduce la pregunta o pregunta en el SO en ingles ;P

Comment: Por favor, traduce tu pregunta al español y cuando lo hagas, añade algo más de información: ¿cómo no funciona? ¿Recibes algún error (y dónde)? También deberías poner de dónde sacaste el código en Internet (para citar la fuente y que sirva de referencia para otros usuarios en caso de que busquen información sobre el tema)

Comment: Ya de paso, te recomiendo que completes el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general (y ganar tu primera medalla) y que leas [ask] en el centro de ayuda, donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: Perdona. Pensé que estaba en el foro de habla inglesa y con las prisas se me olvido explicarme un poco mejor. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí os dejo con la solución que a mi pregunta.

```
        <?php

        $unico= uniqid();

        function redimensionar($imagenoriginal,$maximo){
            global $unico;

            //Cargo en memoria la imagen que quiero redimensionar
                $imagen_original = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagenoriginal);

                //Obtengo el ancho de la imagen quecargue
                $ancho_original = imagesx($imagen_original);

                //Obtengo el alto de la imagen que cargue
                $alto_original = imagesy($imagen_original);

                //SI QUEREMOS UN ANCHO FINAL FIJO, calculamos el ALTO de forma proporcionada
                $ancho_final = $maximo;

                //Ancho final en pixeles
                $alto_final = ($ancho_final / $ancho_original) * $alto_original;

                //Creo una imagen vacia, con el alto y el ancho que tendrá la imagen redimensionada
                $imagen_redimensionada = imagecreatetruecolor($ancho_final, $alto_final);


                //Copio la imagen original con las nuevas dimensiones a la imagen en blanco que creamos en la linea anterior
                imagecopyresampled($imagen_redimensionada, $imagen_original, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ancho_final, $alto_final, $ancho_original, $alto_original);

                //Guardo la imagen ya redimensionada        
                imagejpeg($imagen_redimensionada, $unico.".jpg");

        }


        function ponerFiltro($unico){
            // Creo una imagen png con el logo  o la imagen que utilizaremos
        // como marca de agua
        $marca = imagecreatefrompng('18.png');
        //Creo una imagen temporal de la imagen a marcar
        $imagentemporal = imagecreatefromjpeg($unico);

        // Establecer los márgenes inferiores y derecho de la imagen de marca de agua

        $margenderecho = 0;
        $margeninferior = 0;
        // Establecemos la posicion donde se ubicara la marca
        $posicionx= imagesx($marca);
        $posiciony= imagesy($marca);

        // Copiar la marca de agua sobre la imagen temporal y
        // calculamos la posición de la imagen marca o logo.
        imagecopy($imagentemporal, $marca, imagesx($imagentemporal) - $posicionx- $margenderecho, imagesy($imagentemporal) - $posiciony- $margeninferior, 0, 0, imagesx($marca), imagesy($marca));

        //Guardamos la imagen marcada en un nuevo archivo
        imagepng($imagentemporal, $unico.'nuevaimagen.png');
        // Mostramos imagen con marca y liberar Ram
        //header('Content-type: image/png');
        //imagepng($imagentemporal);
        //imagedestroy($imagentemporal);
        }

        //Redimensiono la imagen a 100px
        redimensionar("https://k38.kn3.net/taringa/2/4/3/0/6/6/13/soyluuchoox/A1D.jpg?1843",100);

        //Vuelvo a redimensionar la imagen a 640px
        redimensionar($unico.".jpg",640);

        //Añado la marca de agua
        ponerFiltro($unico.".jpg");

        //Elimino la foto original y me quedo con la que tiene la marca de agua
        unlink($unico.".jpg");

        //Una vez que se haya enviado el post se eliminar la imagen.

        //unlink($unico.'.jpgnuevaimagen.png');
        ?>
```

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Cómo hacía tiempo que no tocaba php *te voy poniendo los errores* que he ido cometiendo hasta obtener el resultado final (y creo que deseado).

[image: Resultado final de la ejecución del programa]

Posiblemente estos primeros pasos puedes saltartelos. Lo primero que hice fue intentar configurar ST3 pero no fui capaz (no encontraba la **librería GD** -> `Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()`). Por lo que al final instalé WAMP ([siguiendo estas indicaciones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580273/how-to-run-php-files-on-my-computer)) y listo.

Una vez con el código funcionando, el error que encontré fué la asignación directa de una URL a una variable. La solución fue **descargar de la URL la foto que quiero modificar** a un directorio local y seguir trabajando con la imagen descargada como en el código que ya tienes.

Lo único modificado son estas primeras líneas de código:

```
copy('https://ep00.epimg.net/elpais/imagenes/2017/06/05/album/1496652756_562670_1496654035_album_normal.jpg', 'photo.jpg');
$getImagen = 'photo.jpg';
```

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, al final consegui hacerlo por otro metodo.